# How can I edit a view entry from the view, such as a lightswitch check, without opening up the form?

Tags: admin, craft4, editing

In Craft CMS I can see views of my my entries through singles, structures, or channels.

I can see a lightswitch checkbox have a green check in the view.  I'd like to be able to edit the view directly without opening up the form.

If I have 50 entries and I need to quickly check or uncheck them, I don't want to do it 50 times.  Does this feature exist?  If not, is there a custom plugin to do it?  If not, any idea how I myself can make the custom plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this from the CP (although P&T mention [here](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/discussions/8132#discussioncomment-6479823) that it might be in Craft 5), but for the time being you can likely accomplish what you need with a single CLI command. See here: https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/bulk-resaving-elements#resaving-with-specific-field-values

For a lightswitch field, you'd need to set it to 1 (on) or 0 (off). So for example, to turn them on for all entries in a blog section:

```
php craft resave/entries --set myLightSwitchFieldHandle --to 1 --section blog
```